# Learning Mathematica for Math Majors

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, reference-request

I just downloaded Mathematica and I'm taking a course in Multivariable Calculus. I realize there is a lot of complexity to Mathematica and there are Many types of learning resources out there.
I was wondering if someone can point me towards,preferably free, pdfs, sites and other resources that cover just being able to do simple things such as plot functions, plot in 2D and 3D, find contour plots, calculus, find maxima and minima, and perhaps something that even goes into linear alg. etc. Come to think of it, are there any books out there that teach programming for math majors without getting too complicated? Is it worth it for grad school to learn the language more foundationally?

Also what kind of programming does this fall under, functional, data structures, pattern and rule based etc. so I know where to look in books for the topics I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/resources/

Comment: You may also be able to get some material from @David, if he's reading this.

Comment: Browse [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) until you find something you like. Personally I found Sal Mangano's *Mathematica Cookbook* helpful in the beginning. You ask for a lot of specific solutions: how to plot in 2D and 3D, find contours, find maxima and minima etc. and in the cookbook you can easily find what you are looking for. In other books this information may be buried, at least to a larger extent.